# Building Authorize.Net iOS SDK Fails using build.sh for XCode5-DP6

Tags: sdk, authorize.net, xcode5

I am getting the following error trying to build the SDK using the given build.sh file. Below is the log file. It gives me the error that the Architecture is not supported

```
=== BUILD TARGET ANMobilePaymentLib OF PROJECT ANMobilePaymentLib WITH CONFIGURATION Release ===

Check dependencies

ProcessPCH /var/folders/z0/65n1rtbx7yx5_mpzs24mydr40000gn/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/5.0-5A11386k/Xcode/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/ANMobilePaymentLib_Prefix-gcmzxydgikrysqehjeesnqusllqc/ANMobilePaymentLib_Prefix.pch.pch ANMobilePaymentLib_Prefix.pch normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    cd /Users/ankur/Desktop/anet_ios_sdk-1.1.1
    setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode5-DP6.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode5-DP6.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/Users/ankur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin:/Users/ankur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/bin:/Users/ankur/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin:/Users/ankur/.rvm/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin"
    /Applications/Xcode5-DP6.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c-header -arch i386 -fmessage-length=116 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -fcolor-diagnostics -std=c99 -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -Os -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Wno-receiver-is-weak -Wno-arc-repeated-use-of-weak -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wno-empty-body -Wno-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wno-constant-conversion -Wno-int-conversion -Wno-bool-conversion -Wno-enum-conversion -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wno-undeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -isysroot /Applications/Xcode5-DP6.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk -fexceptions -fasm-blocks -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -g -Wno-sign-conversion -fobjc-abi-version=2 -fobjc-legacy-dispatch -mios-simulator-version-min=4.0 -iquote /Users/ankur/Desktop/anet_ios_sdk-1.1.1/build/ANMobilePaymentLib.build/Release-iphonesimulator/ANMobilePaymentLib.build/ANMobilePaymentLib-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/ankur/Desktop/anet_ios_sdk-1.1.1/build/ANMobilePaymentLib.build/Release-iphonesimulator/ANMobilePaymentLib.build/ANMobilePaymentLib-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/ankur/Desktop/anet_ios_sdk-1.1.1/build/ANMobilePaymentLib.build/Release-iphonesimulator/ANMobilePaymentLib.build/ANMobilePaymentLib-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/ankur/Desktop/anet_ios_sdk-1.1.1/build/ANMobilePaymentLib.build/Release-iphonesimulator/ANMobilePaymentLib.build/ANMobilePaymentLib-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/ankur/Desktop/anet_ios_sdk-1.1.1/build/Release-iphonesimulator/include -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/libxml2/libxml -I/Users/ankur/Desktop/anet_ios_sdk-1.1.1/build/ANMobilePaymentLib.build/Release-iphonesimulator/ANMobilePaymentLib.build/DerivedSources/i386 -I/Users/ankur/Desktop/anet_ios_sdk-1.1.1/build/ANMobilePaymentLib.build/Release-iphonesimulator/ANMobilePaymentLib.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/ankur/Desktop/anet_ios_sdk-1.1.1/build/Release-iphonesimulator -F/Xcode4/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.2.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks --serialize-diagnostics /var/folders/z0/65n1rtbx7yx5_mpzs24mydr40000gn/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/5.0-5A11386k/Xcode/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/ANMobilePaymentLib_Prefix-gcmzxydgikrysqehjeesnqusllqc/ANMobilePaymentLib_Prefix.pch.dia -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /var/folders/z0/65n1rtbx7yx5_mpzs24mydr40000gn/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/5.0-5A11386k/Xcode/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/ANMobilePaymentLib_Prefix-gcmzxydgikrysqehjeesnqusllqc/ANMobilePaymentLib_Prefix.pch.d -c /Users/ankur/Desktop/anet_ios_sdk-1.1.1/ANMobilePaymentLib_Prefix.pch -o /var/folders/z0/65n1rtbx7yx5_mpzs24mydr40000gn/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/5.0-5A11386k/Xcode/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/ANMobilePaymentLib_Prefix-gcmzxydgikrysqehjeesnqusllqc/ANMobilePaymentLib_Prefix.pch.pch

ProcessPCH /var/folders/z0/65n1rtbx7yx5_mpzs24mydr40000gn/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/5.0-5A11386k/Xcode/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/ANMobilePaymentLib_Prefix-gceiyboxjftlrxcuxeqwejycgqjs/ANMobilePaymentLib_Prefix.pch.pch ANMobilePaymentLib_Prefix.pch normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    cd /Users/ankur/Desktop/anet_ios_sdk-1.1.1
    setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode5-DP6.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode5-DP6.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/Users/ankur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin:/Users/ankur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/bin:/Users/ankur/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin:/Users/ankur/.rvm/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin"
    /Applications/Xcode5-DP6.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c-header -arch x86_64 -fmessage-length=116 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -fcolor-diagnostics -std=c99 -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -Os -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Wno-receiver-is-weak -Wno-arc-repeated-use-of-weak -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wno-empty-body -Wno-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wno-constant-conversion -Wno-int-conversion -Wno-bool-conversion -Wno-enum-conversion -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wno-undeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -isysroot /Applications/Xcode5-DP6.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk -fexceptions -fasm-blocks -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -g -Wno-sign-conversion -fobjc-abi-version=2 -fobjc-legacy-dispatch -mios-simulator-version-min=4.0 -iquote /Users/ankur/Desktop/anet_ios_sdk-1.1.1/build/ANMobilePaymentLib.build/Release-iphonesimulator/ANMobilePaymentLib.build/ANMobilePaymentLib-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/ankur/Desktop/anet_ios_sdk-1.1.1/build/ANMobilePaymentLib.build/Release-iphonesimulator/ANMobilePaymentLib.build/ANMobilePaymentLib-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/ankur/Desktop/anet_ios_sdk-1.1.1/build/ANMobilePaymentLib.build/Release-iphonesimulator/ANMobilePaymentLib.build/ANMobilePaymentLib-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/ankur/Desktop/anet_ios_sdk-1.1.1/build/ANMobilePaymentLib.build/Release-iphonesimulator/ANMobilePaymentLib.build/ANMobilePaymentLib-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/ankur/Desktop/anet_ios_sdk-1.1.1/build/Release-iphonesimulator/include -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/libxml2/libxml -I/Users/ankur/Desktop/anet_ios_sdk-1.1.1/build/ANMobilePaymentLib.build/Release-iphonesimulator/ANMobilePaymentLib.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -I/Users/ankur/Desktop/anet_ios_sdk-1.1.1/build/ANMobilePaymentLib.build/Release-iphonesimulator/ANMobilePaymentLib.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/ankur/Desktop/anet_ios_sdk-1.1.1/build/Release-iphonesimulator -F/Xcode4/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.2.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks --serialize-diagnostics /var/folders/z0/65n1rtbx7yx5_mpzs24mydr40000gn/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/5.0-5A11386k/Xcode/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/ANMobilePaymentLib_Prefix-gceiyboxjftlrxcuxeqwejycgqjs/ANMobilePaymentLib_Prefix.pch.dia -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /var/folders/z0/65n1rtbx7yx5_mpzs24mydr40000gn/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/5.0-5A11386k/Xcode/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/ANMobilePaymentLib_Prefix-gceiyboxjftlrxcuxeqwejycgqjs/ANMobilePaymentLib_Prefix.pch.d -c /Users/ankur/Desktop/anet_ios_sdk-1.1.1/ANMobilePaymentLib_Prefix.pch -o /var/folders/z0/65n1rtbx7yx5_mpzs24mydr40000gn/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/5.0-5A11386k/Xcode/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/ANMobilePaymentLib_Prefix-gceiyboxjftlrxcuxeqwejycgqjs/ANMobilePaymentLib_Prefix.pch.pch
In file included from /Users/ankur/Desktop/anet_ios_sdk-1.1.1/ANMobilePaymentLib_Prefix.pch:6:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode5-DP6.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:6:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode5-DP6.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:11:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode5-DP6.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk/usr/include/sys/types.h:75:
/Applications/Xcode5-DP6.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:654:2: error: 
      Unsupported architecture
#error Unsupported architecture
 ^
1 error generated.
Command /Applications/Xcode5-DP6.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1

** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    ProcessPCH /var/folders/z0/65n1rtbx7yx5_mpzs24mydr40000gn/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/5.0-5A11386k/Xcode/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/ANMobilePaymentLib_Prefix-gceiyboxjftlrxcuxeqwejycgqjs/ANMobilePaymentLib_Prefix.pch.pch ANMobilePaymentLib_Prefix.pch normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)
+ failed build
+ echo 'Failed: build'
Failed: build
+ exit 1
```